# Better ways to keep 2 same variables that is controlled by a external variable as array in a class

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I have a class, all the parameters of the class -except one that is detect value- have 2 values that is controlled by the detect value. See the implementation below.
I have a detect value that is controlled by external sources. With this value get are set methods map to 2 variables.

I realized this as array of length 2, but I am curious about other ways. Any recommendations and improvements to the question is appreciated.

I am a new developer in this project. I thought that using singleton like extension like doubleton may be OK, but I am a bit reluctant to change the structure of the project. If I am more confident about better ways, I will be more courageous to request change in the structure of the project.

My first aim to find if there are better ways to do this 2 same variables in a class better than using arrays.

```
class Fun
{
    int detect;
    int a[2], b[2], c[2];

    void Apply(byte[] ar)
    {
        detect = ar[0];
        if(detect == 1)
        {
            a[0] = ar[1];
            b[0] = ar[2];
            c[0] = ar[3];
        }
        if(detect == 2)
        {
            a[1] = ar[1];
            b[1] = ar[2];
            c[1] = ar[3];
        }
    }

    byte [] GetAll(int detect)
    {
        int [] ar = new int [3];
        if(detect = 1)
        {
            ar[0] = a[0];
            ar[1] = b[0];
            ar[2] = c[0];       
        }
        if(detect = 2)
        {
            ar[0] = a[1];
            ar[1] = b[1];
            ar[2] = c[1];       
        }       
    }

    GetA(int detect)
    {

        if(detect == 1)
        {
            return a[0];
        }
        if(detect == 2)
        {
            return a[1];
        }
    }
    SetA(int detect, int val)
    {
        if(detect == 1)
        {
            a[0] = val;
        }
        if(detect == 2)
        {
            a[1] = val;
        }
    }
    // GetB, GetC, SetB, SetC are similar

}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking and the code you posted makes no sense so I cannot even use that to deduce anything.  Please edit your question with a clear problem statement and include a [MCVE]

Comment: Why does the class need the field `detect`? It is most of the time local and the one time it's not, it should be.

Comment: @Fildor You are right, detect is unncessary at the third line on the class, thanks.

Comment: Just a sidenode: Please use more "speaking" var names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 2 dimensional array and your methods can be much simpler:

```
class Fun
{
    int detect;
    int a[2][3];

    void Apply(byte[] ar)
    {
        detect = ar[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            a[detect - 1][i] = ar[i];
    }

    public int[] GetAll(int detect)
    {
        int[] ar = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            ar[i] = a[detect - 1][i];
        return ar;
    }

    GetA(int detect)
    {
        return a[detect - 1][0];
    }
    SetA(int detect, int val)
    {
        a[detect - 1][0] = val;
    }
    GetB(int detect)
    {
        return a[detect - 1][1];
    }
    SetB(int detect, int val)
    {
        a[detect - 1][1] = val;
    }
    GetC(int detect)
    {
        return a[detect - 1][2];
    }
    SetC(int detect, int val)
    {
        a[detect - 1][2] = val;
    }

}
```

Note: if you provide a value other than 1 or 2 for detect you can expect an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Unrelated: In none of those methods the incoming arrays are checked. Never trust user input ...

Comment: Thanks for a better alternative

Answer (score 0):

A different and probably more sensible approach would be to have two instances of a simpler class:

```
public class Fun
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
    public void Apply(byte[] ar)
    {
        A = ar[0];
        B = ar[1];
        C = ar[2];
    }
    public byte[] GetAll()
    {
        byte[] ar = new byte[3];
        ar[0] = A;
        ar[1] = B;
        ar[2] = C;
    }
}

public class NotFun
{
    Fun fun1 = new Fun();
    Fun fun2 = new Fun();

    void Something()
    {
        fun1.Apply(new byte[3] { 1, 2, 3 });
        int a = fun1.A;
    }
}
```